# Angularjs if construction in expression

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Here is my code: how can I call this function `data-clipboard-text="{{sharedLink()}}"` only if `currentPageShared===true`

```
<md-button ng-click="toggleShare()" ngclipboard 
data-clipboard-text="{{sharedLink()}}">
          {{(currentPageShared===true) ? 'Stop Sharing Page' : 'Share Page'}}
</md-button>
```

Comment: Can't you just check it if `currentPageShared` is true with a simple `if` inside the sharedLink() function?

Comment: FYI,
No Control Flow Statements: You cannot use the following in an Angular expression: conditionals, loops, or exceptions.
Filters: You can use filters within expressions to format data before displaying it. for more info check out the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
data-clipboard-text="{{currentPageShared?sharedLink():""}}"
```

Comment: data-clipboard-text="{{true?sharedLink():""}}" just add this code, and check is it working

Answer (score 0):

```
<md-button ng-click="toggleShare()" ngclipboard data-clipboard-text="{{sharedLink()}}" ng-if="currentPageShared">
      Stop Sharing Page
</md-button>
<md-button ng-click="toggleShare()" ngclipboard data-clipboard-text="{{sharedLink()}}" ng-if="!currentPageShared">
      Share Page
</md-button>
```

That should work.

Comment: Ng-if is not a solution. The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM,

Answer (score 0):

Im my case the solution was to migrate to https://github.com/omichelsen/angular-clipboard